# How to subscribe event listener to the collection?

Tags: c#, events, collections

I have a collection in `class A`:

```
class A{
  public static List<A> list = new List<A>();
}
```

I would like to insert a code in `class B` that monitors that collection from `class A` and if this collection changes its' size there will be method invoked : `collectionSizeChanged()`

```
class B{
......
   public void collectionSizeChanged(){
    // some code modifing private objects in class B
  }
}
```

Comment: In class A, could you use an `ObservableCollection` instead?

Comment: @AlexandreRondeau I do not know that. How to do so?

Comment: An [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for. It's a List<T>, but with event when items are added or removed from the collection

Comment: @AlexandreRondeau How to detect that event in `class B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List doesn't expose any event, but you could use an `ObservableCollection<T>` to do the job.

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
observableCollection.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => 
    {
        doStuff();
    }

class A
{
     public static ObservableCollection<A> list = new ObservableCollection<A>();
}

class B
{
    public void StartListening()
    {
        A.list.CollectionChanged += collectionSizeChanged;
    }
    public void StopListening()
    {
        A.list.CollectionChanged -= collectionSizeChanged;
    }

    private void collectionSizeChange(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`List` (or `List<T>`) does not provide that functionality out of the box. You may want to look into using an ObservableCollection instead or roll your own class that contains a list but raises the events you need.

Comment: I changed the type of the collection. But I do not know how to detect the size change in class B and invoke method.

Comment: you must subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of the collection.